# Python asyncio multithread wrapper

Tags: python, multithreading, asyncio

For my application, I needed a lightweight way to launch multiple tasks and monitor their completion in a main loop periodically or use callbacks. The main loop is going to be busy most of the time performing analysis after receiving inputs from tasks. I was writing a lot of boilerplate code for **asyncio** each time and decided to write this multi-threaded queue/dispatcher outlined below. New to Python and still learning the ropes, so looking for two things:

1. Are there known packages for my use case?
2. Could I run into thread locks with the approach below for the intended scale (2-3 threads, 20-30 tasks each)?

**Dispatcher package**

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread, Lock
from SeTools.Printer import mprint

"""
Task Ion is a holder for the task and attributes such as coro, callback, and timeout associated with it.
"""


class TaskIon:
    def __init__(self, name, taskCoro, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Initialize a taskIon which is then used to invoke an asyncio Task
        :param name: name of task; this is the primary key you will need to cancel or fetch task results
        :param taskCoro: the coroutine to be called
        :param args: args for the coroutine
        :param kwargs: supported values are:
                "callback" - the routine to call after tasks completed or is cancelled. Passes the task object to callback
                "timeout" - timeout in seconds for the Task
                "wrappedCall" - when set to True, the coro is called using executor. Useful when you don't want a synchronous task to block
        """
        self.name = name
        self.coro = taskCoro
        self.coroArgs = args
        self.callback = kwargs["callback"] if "callback" in kwargs else None #callbackRoutine
        self.timeout = kwargs["timeout"] if "timeout" in kwargs else None
        self.wrappedCall = kwargs["wrappedCall"] if "wrappedCall" in kwargs else False

"""
A workerIon is an independent asyncio loop running any number of tasks and storing results 
"""


class workerIon:
    def _init_caller(self, future, ion):
        pass

    def sleepThread(self, sleepTime):
        """
        Ask the worker to make thread sleep for time
        :param sleepTime:
        :return:
        """
        self.loopStatus = "paused"
        time.sleep(sleepTime)
        self.loopStatus = "started"

    def __init__(self, name, taskRequests: list[TaskIon]):
        self.loopStartTime: datetime = None
        self.loopEndTime: datetime = None
        self.name = name
        self.results = {}
        self.tasks: dict[str, asyncio.Task] = {}
        self.loopHandle = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        self.taskStatus = {}
        self.loopStatus = "initializing"
        self._taskIons = taskRequests
        for t in taskRequests: self.taskStatus[t] = "not started"

    def startLoop(self):
        self.loopHandle.run_until_complete(self._loop(self._taskIons))
        # self._loop(self._taskIons)

    async def _wrappedTask(self, coro, *args):
        return await self.loopHandle.run_in_executor(None, coro, *args)

    async def _loop(self, rTasks: list[TaskIon]):
        self.loopStartTime = datetime.now()
        self.loopStatus = "started"
        mprint(f"Dispatcher-worker : {self.name} loop started at time: {self.loopStartTime}")
        rtask: TaskIon
        for rtask in rTasks:
            if Dispatcher.taskExists(rtask.name):
                raise KeyError(f"Global task tracker: {rtask.name} already started as task and hasn't been fetched")
            if rtask.wrappedCall:
                t = self.loopHandle.create_task(self._wrappedTask(rtask.coro, *rtask.coroArgs), name=rtask.name)
            else:
                t = self.loopHandle.create_task(rtask.coro(*rtask.coroArgs), name=rtask.name)

            self.taskStatus[rtask.name] = "started"
            if rtask.callback is not None:
                t.add_done_callback(rtask.callback)
            self.tasks[rtask.name] = t
            await Dispatcher.addTaskAsync(rtask.name, t)

        while True:

            try:
                done, pending = await asyncio.wait(self.tasks.values(), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                for t in done:
                    tName = t.get_name()
                    self.results[tName] = t.result()
                    self.taskStatus[tName] = "completed"
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                self.taskStatus[tName] = "cancelled"
            finally:
                self.tasks.pop(t.get_name())
                if len(self.tasks) <= 0:
                    break

        self.loopStatus = "completed"
        self.loopEndTime = datetime.now()
        self.loopHandle.stop()
        mprint(f"Dispatcher-worker : {self.name} loop ending at time: {self.loopEndTime}")
        Dispatcher.unregisterThread(self)


"""
Dispatcher allows you to launch many concurrent tasks synchronously or asynchronously 
"""


class Dispatcher:
    _tasks: dict[str, asyncio.Task] = {}
    _workers: dict[str, workerIon] = {}
    _threads: dict[str, Thread] = {}
    _asyncioLock = asyncio.Lock()
    _threadLock = Lock()

    @staticmethod
    def unregisterThread(worker: workerIon):
        """
        Immidiately
        :param worker:
        :return:
        """
        if worker.name not in Dispatcher._threads:
            raise KeyError(f"Thread {worker.name} not registered")
        else:
            with Dispatcher._threadLock:
                Dispatcher._threads.pop(worker.name)
                mprint(f"Thread {worker.name} unregistered after completion")

    @staticmethod
    def isTaskDone(name, silent=False):
        if name not in Dispatcher._tasks:
            if not silent:
                raise KeyError(f"Task with name: {name} not registered in tasks")
            else:
                return False
        return Dispatcher._tasks[name].done()

    @staticmethod
    def taskExists(name) -> bool:
        """
        Returns whether a task was registered. A task doesn't leave a queue until the results are fetched.
        :param name: name of task to search
        :return: bool
        """
        return name in Dispatcher._tasks

    @staticmethod
    async def addTaskAsync(name, task) -> None:
        """
        Adds a task to global tracker. Thread safe
        :param name: name of task to add. A task doesn't leave a queue until the results are fetched.
        :param task: the task object created inside the worker
        :return: None
        """
        with Dispatcher._threadLock:
            async with Dispatcher._asyncioLock:
                Dispatcher._tasks[name] = task
                # mprint(f"task added: {task.get_name()}")

    @staticmethod
    def addWorker(name, worker) -> None:
        """
        Add a worked to queue. A worker does not leave queue until all tasks in worker are finished and results fetched
        :param name: Name of worker to add
        :param worker: the workerIon object
        :return: None
        """
        if name in Dispatcher._workers:
            raise KeyError(
                f"Worker with {name} already added. Try fetching all results to remove from queue or change name")
        Dispatcher._workers[name] = worker

    @staticmethod
    def launchTasks(tasks: list[TaskIon], name=None) -> None:
        """
        Create a new workerIon and start one or more tasks in parallel. Launch tasks is synchronous and will block
        execution until all tasks complete
        :param tasks:
        :param name: name of workerIon
        :return: None
        """
        name = datetime.now().timestamp() if name is None else name
        w = workerIon(name, tasks)
        for rtask in tasks:
            Dispatcher.addWorker(rtask.name, w)
        w.startLoop()

    @staticmethod
    async def addWorkerAsync(name, worker):
        async with Dispatcher._asyncioLock:
            Dispatcher._workers[name] = worker

    @staticmethod
    def launchTasksAsync(tasks: list[TaskIon], name=None) -> str:
        """

        :param tasks:
        :param name:
        :return:
        """
        name = datetime.now().timestamp() if name is None else name
        with Dispatcher._threadLock:
            if name in Dispatcher._threads:
                raise KeyError(
                    f"Thread with {name} is already in queue, and alive status: {Dispatcher._threads[name].is_alive()}")
            else:
                Dispatcher._threads[name] = Thread(target=Dispatcher.launchTasks, name=name, args=(tasks, name))
                Dispatcher._threads[name].start()
                time.sleep(0.1)
        return name

    @staticmethod
    def wait(name=None) -> None:
        """
        :param name:
        :return:
        """
        if name is not None:
            if name not in Dispatcher._threads:
                return None
            else:
                return Dispatcher._threads[name].join()
        else:
            for t in threading.enumerate():
                if t.name in Dispatcher._threads: # "MainThread":
                    mprint(f"Thread {t.name} will be waited")
                    t.join()
                # Dispatcher._threads[t].join()
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def popTaskResult(taskName, silent=False):
        res = Dispatcher.getTaskResult(taskName, silent)
        if Dispatcher.taskStatus(taskName, silent) in ("completed", "cancelled"):
            Dispatcher.cleanupTask(taskName, silent=silent)
        return res

    @staticmethod
    def getTaskResult(taskName, silent=False):
        """

        :param taskName:
        :param silent:
        :return:
        """
        if taskName not in Dispatcher._tasks:
            if not silent:
                raise KeyError(f"Task with name: {taskName} not registered in tasks")
            else:
                return None

        if not Dispatcher.isTaskDone(taskName):
            if not silent:
                raise Exception(f"Task name: {taskName} has not finished")
            else:
                return None

        if taskName not in Dispatcher._workers:
            if not silent:
                raise Exception(f"Worker name: {taskName} has not been registered yet")
            else:
                return None

        if taskName not in Dispatcher._workers[taskName].results:
            if not silent:
                raise Exception(f"Task name: {taskName} has not registered results yet")
            else:
                return None

        result = Dispatcher._workers[taskName].results[taskName]
        # Dispatcher.cleanup(taskName)
        # Dispatcher._tasks.pop(taskName)
        return result

    @staticmethod
    def taskNamesForWorker(workerName) -> [str]:
        """

        :param workerName:
        :return:
        """
        names = []
        for key, _w in Dispatcher._workers.items():
            if _w.name == workerName:
                names.append(key)
        return names

    @staticmethod
    def taskStatus(taskName, silent=False) -> str:
        """

        :param taskName:
        :param silent:
        :return:
        """
        if taskName not in Dispatcher._workers or taskName not in Dispatcher._workers[taskName].taskStatus:
            if not silent:
                raise KeyError(f"Task {taskName} not registered yet")
            else:
                return "not registered"
        else:
            return Dispatcher._workers[taskName].taskStatus[taskName]

    @staticmethod
    def cleanupTask(taskName=None, force=False, silent=False):
        if taskName is not None:
            with Dispatcher._threadLock:
                task = Dispatcher._tasks[taskName]
                if not task.done():
                    if not force:
                        if silent:
                            return None
                        else:
                            raise Exception(f"Task: {taskName} is in progress")
                    else:
                        # mprint(f"Cancelling due to invoke of cleanup with force for task: {taskName}")
                        Dispatcher._workers[taskName].loopHandle.call_soon_threadsafe(task.cancel)
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                # Now that task is done we can cleanup the task store and result store
                worker = Dispatcher._workers[taskName]
                if taskName in worker.results: _ = worker.results.pop(taskName)  # cleanup results
                # if taskName in worker.tasks: _ = worker.tasks.pop(taskName) # The worker will cleanup the task
                if taskName in Dispatcher._tasks: _ = Dispatcher._tasks.pop(taskName)
                    # mprint(f"task removed: {taskName}")
                if taskName in Dispatcher._workers: _ = Dispatcher._workers.pop(
                    taskName)  # cleanup the task to worker mapping table
                # Check if last task in thread and release thread if so.
                taskNamesLeft = Dispatcher.taskNamesForWorker(worker.name)
                if len(taskNamesLeft) <= 0:
                    mprint(f"No more tasks left in worker {taskNamesLeft}")
        else:  # cleanup all tasks
            tNames = list(Dispatcher._tasks.keys())
            for tName in tNames:
                mprint(f"Cleaning up task: {tName}, force={force}, silent={silent}")
                Dispatcher.cleanupTask(tName, force, silent)

    @staticmethod
    def cleanupThread(threadName=None, force=False, silent=False):
        if threadName is not None:
            with Dispatcher._threadLock:
                thread = Dispatcher._threads[threadName]
                if not thread.is_alive():
                    if not force:
                        if silent:
                            return None
                        else:
                            raise Exception(f"Thread: {thread.name} is in progress")
                    else:
                        for wTask in Dispatcher.taskNamesForWorker(threadName):
                            Dispatcher.cleanupTask(wTask, force, silent)
                        time.sleep(0.01)

                if threadName in Dispatcher._threads: _ = Dispatcher._threads.pop(threadName)
        else:  # cleanup all tasks
            tNames = list(Dispatcher._threads.keys())
            for tName in tNames:
                Dispatcher.cleanupThread(tName, force, silent)

    @staticmethod
    def printThreads():
        mprint(f"Threads: {Dispatcher._threads.keys()}")
```

**Testcase**

```
from Dispatcher import *
from SeTools.Printer import mprint
# Testing the file directly
if __name__ == '__main__':
    async def printHelloAndSleep(name, j):
        try:
            await asyncio.sleep(j)
            return f"Result -- TaskName: {name}: -- sleep-time: {j} -- end-time: {datetime.now()}"
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
            mprint(f"Task {name} cancelled, printed from coro")
            raise


    def callbackTest(future: asyncio.Task):
        if not future.cancelled():
            mprint(f"Another way to get results: {future.result()}")
        else:
            mprint(f"Task {future.get_name()} cancelled, printed from callback")


    mprint(f"Main loop start time: {datetime.now()}")
    mprint(f"Task1 status: {Dispatcher.taskStatus('task1', silent=True)}")
    nameT1 = Dispatcher.launchTasksAsync([
        TaskIon("task1", printHelloAndSleep("Task1", 4)),
        TaskIon("task2", printHelloAndSleep("Task2", 200), callbackTest)])
    nameT2 = Dispatcher.launchTasksAsync([
        TaskIon("task3", printHelloAndSleep("Task3", 10)),
        TaskIon("task4", printHelloAndSleep("Task4", 11))])

    mprint(f"Task1 status: {Dispatcher.taskStatus('task1', silent=True)}")
    mprint(f"Main loop tasks launched: {datetime.now()}")
    time.sleep(1)

    Dispatcher.cleanupTask("task2", force=True)
    mprint(f"Task1 status: {Dispatcher.taskStatus('task1', silent=True)}")
    Dispatcher.printThreads()
    while True:
        x = Dispatcher.popTaskResult("task1", silent=True)
        if x is not None:
            mprint(x)
            break
    mprint(f"Task1 status: {Dispatcher.taskStatus('task1', silent=True)}")
    Dispatcher.printThreads()
    time.sleep(2)
    Dispatcher.printThreads()
    Dispatcher.wait()
    Dispatcher.printThreads()
```

**Output**

```
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 21] -- Main loop start time: 2022-02-25 13:33:42.676244
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 22] -- Task1 status: not registered
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 58] -- Dispatcher-worker : 1645824822.760012 loop started at time: 2022-02-25 13:33:42.768744
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 58] -- Dispatcher-worker : 1645824822.868929 loop started at time: 2022-02-25 13:33:42.870863
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 30] -- Task1 status: started
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 31] -- Main loop tasks launched: 2022-02-25 13:33:42.984696
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 10] -- Task Task2 cancelled, printed from coro
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 35] -- Task1 status: started
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 348] -- Threads: dict_keys([1645824822.760012, 1645824822.868929])
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 18] -- Task task2 cancelled, printed from callback
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 317] -- No more tasks left in worker []
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 40] -- Result -- TaskName: Task1: -- sleep-time: 4 -- end-time: 2022-02-25 13:33:46.928457
[Info] -- [Dispatcher_copy.py, 42] -- Task1 status: not registered
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 88] -- Dispatcher-worker : 1645824822.760012 loop ending at time: 2022-02-25 13:33:46.928457
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 348] -- Threads: dict_keys([1645824822.760012, 1645824822.868929])
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 116] -- Thread 1645824822.760012 unregistered after completion
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 348] -- Threads: dict_keys([1645824822.868929])
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 88] -- Dispatcher-worker : 1645824822.868929 loop ending at time: 2022-02-25 13:33:53.919234
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 116] -- Thread 1645824822.868929 unregistered after completion
[Info] -- [Dispatcher.py, 348] -- Threads: dict_keys([])

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: The first thing that came to my eye is your import of `Lock`. If you want concurrency, you [don't want locks](https://youtu.be/APUCMSPiNh4?t=699). If you *think* you need locks, you should redesign your code. I may come back to you with a detailed review if I find the time, since writing concurrent code is running with scissors.

Comment: IO-bound or CPU-bound?

Comment: tasks are io-bound, main thread will be cpu-bound

Comment: I might be wrong as I'm not an expert, but Apache Airflow seems to be a potential tool for this. I've been playing with it on my local machine. You can create a graph of tasks (DAGs) with a Python code, and you can see all sort of summaries in a browser. You can even watch on the graph view all the task states. There are several executors including celery, kubernetes. And there are managed versions on cloud. 
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

> are there known packages for my use case?

Yes.

Use 0mq, RabbitMQ, kafka, or similar pub/sub platform,
to address horizontal scaling issues.